# Apache Solr extension in PHP - Solr HTTP Error : 'Couldn't connect to server'

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to install the Apache Solr extension for PHP on my Windows box.
A quick look at phpinfo(); shows that the extension has been loaded.[image]

Apart from changing SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME to match my own Virtual Host, everything as the same as on the [PHP Solr Example page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php).
When I run solr_test.php, I get the following error:

```
Warning: SolrClient::addDocument(): Solr HTTP Error : 'Couldn't connect to server'
```

The [PHP Solr page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.solr.php) says: The Solr extension allows you to communicate effectively with the Apache Solr server in PHP 5 so I am assuming that I do not need to run anything else to make this extension work.  Is that correct?

Do I need to set up an additional Virtual Host for Solr, e.g solr.mysite?

Here is my bootstrap.php file:

```
<?php

/* Domain name of the Solr server */
define('SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME', 'test.mysite');

/* Whether or not to run in secure mode */
define('SOLR_SECURE', true);

/* HTTP Port to connection */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8443 : 8983));

/* HTTP Basic Authentication Username */
define('SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME', 'admin');

/* HTTP Basic Authentication password */
define('SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'changeit');

/* HTTP connection timeout */
/* This is maximum time in seconds allowed for the http data transfer operation.     Default value is 30 seconds */
define('SOLR_SERVER_TIMEOUT', 10);

?>
```

Here is my solr_test.php page:

```
<?php

include "bootstrap.php";

$options = array
(
'hostname' => SOLR_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
'login'    => SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME,
'password' => SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD,
'port'     => SOLR_SERVER_PORT,
);

$client = new SolrClient($options);

$doc = new SolrInputDocument();

$doc->addField('id', 334455);
$doc->addField('cat', 'Software');
$doc->addField('cat', 'Lucene');

$updateResponse = $client->addDocument($doc);

print_r($updateResponse->getResponse());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm a bit concerned about this line here:</strike>

```
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', ((SOLR_SECURE) ? 8443 : 8983));
```

As far as I'm aware this type of logic will only be supported in PHP 5.6. That said I feel like your PHP script should error out. See if something like

```
define('SOLR_SERVER_PORT', 8983);
```

remedies the situation.

Comment: No statically defining SOLR_SERVER_PORT made no difference.

Do I need to open up port 8983 somehow or instruct Apache to "listen". I can view all open ports in Netstat, and 8983 is not open.  BTW, I am using XAMPP, PHP 5.4

Comment: I see. How about you try to use ping() to get some more information? try { $client->ping(); } catch (\Exception $e) { //... }

Comment: ping does not work since the server is down.  Warning: SolrClient::ping() [solrclient.ping]: Solr HTTP Error : 'Couldn't connect to server'

Comment: I guess I misread your previous comment: so the port is not listed by netstat you're saying? In that case I suggest tailing the Solr server log files as a good starting point for figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Solr server details are correct. I get this error only when I pass something wrong like SOLR_SERVER_PORT etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following terminal commands may helps, to disable temporary firewall settings:

```
sestatus
setenforce Permissive
```